# how to get model primary key value after save

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i have a problem when i try to get the primary key (auto increment) from the db after i save the model.

In the database the tabel doesn't have a primary key so i set it using this:

```
public static function primaryKey(){
    return ['id_cod'];
}
```

And i removed it from the models rules.

When i save the model, all the data is saved on the db included `id_cod`, but if i try to access to this property it gives me null.

```
$evento = new Evento();
//populate the model with some data
//..... eg: $evento->name = 'name';
//save model
$evento->save();
$evento->refresh();

echo Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertID(); // gives me the correct id_cod but i think it's not the correct way
echo $evento->id_cod;//gives me null
echo $evento->name;//gives me name
```

How can i get the id_cod just after save the model?

Comment: New `Model`? It should be instance of ActiveRecord. Or is it a one, you just named it Model?

Comment: i'll name it Model for example, it is an istance of ActiveRecord. I'll update the question with another name

Comment: How is `id_cod` generated in the database? Has the `save` method returned `true`?

Comment: id_cod is autoincrement , and it is created (`getLastInsertID()` gives me the correct id_cod). Save method returns true (and the model is validate).

Comment: So maybe you put the properties in the model, like `public $id_cod;`.

Comment: @Bizley that should not be needed. All columns from DB table has their counterpart properties handled by `ActiveRecord`.

Comment: @MichalHynčica not only not needed, simply wrong, but it's a common mistake to put the properties manually.

Comment: It looks like `ActiveRecord::insertInternal` sets primary key values based on result returned by `Schema::insert()`. That method looks for primary key in table schema not in model's `primaryKey()` method. So the `getLastInsertID()` is probably only way left to get that ID. But it might be better to use `$evento->getDb()` instead of `Yii::$app->db`.

Comment: I don't set `public $id_cod;` .  Using `$evento->getDb()` works fine but why it might be better?

Comment: Try to get `id_cod` through `static::getDb()->getLastInsertID()` in `afterSave` of `Model` and set it to `id_cod` property of `Model`?

Comment: @Sfili_81 because using `$evento->getDb` will make sure that you use same instance of `\yii\db\Connection` that has been used for saving the model. That might save you some trouble in future if you need to use multiple db connections. Also the `Yii::$app->component` concept seems to be somehow abandoned in upcoming Yii 3 in favor of dependency injection. So again it might help you if you decide to migrate your app to Yii 3.

Comment: try commenting $evento->refresh();